# Why is my subsurf modifier is shown differently in render?

Tags: modifiers

I've been working with Blender for one week only, after working with Maya so everything is new for me.

I tried to put a modifier on my object and I saw that it is shown differently in the viewport and render.

[image]

can I somehow fix this?

Comment: Usually this happens because of difference in Subsurf modifier levels but it appears to not be the case according to the modifier stack. Is the object seen in preview the one actually rendered? (are there any hidden objects in viewport?) If possible upload your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and [edit] the question with link

Comment: it is was a hidden object that I hid in case everything goes wrong and forgot about it. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @ATopHat you can add an answer yourself, to explain what was causing that, so that the question will result answered (you can also accept it after a short delay, iirc)